# How to transpose table with different number of column using Python?

Tags: python, csv, transpose

I need help in transposing these example from row to column. I know I can use Microsoft Excel to do this but since I will be working with bigger file ( > 1 million row), I want to know if there is a way of doing it using python.

input.csv

```
-0.02 | -120.38 |         |
-0.01 | -120.38 |  -120.1 |
-0.02 | -120.4  |         |
-0.01 | -70.45  |         |
0     |  10.34  |   3.4   | 3.4
0.1   |  20.21  |   90.45 |
0.2   |  90.45  |   110.3 |
```

What I'm hoping for is to get this result

output.csv

```
-0.02   |   -0.01   | -0.02  |  -0.01  |    0     | 0.1   | 0.2
-120.38 |   -120.38 | -120.4 |  -70.45 |    10.34 | 20.21 | 90.45
        |   -120.1  |        |         |    3.4   | 90.45 | 110.3
        |           |        |         |    3.4   |       |
```

But what I get is this result

```
-0.02   |   -0.01   | -0.02  |  -0.01  |    0     | 0.1   | 0.2
-120.38 |   -120.38 | -120.4 |  -70.45 |    10.34 | 20.21 | 90.45
```

It only print out the first two row.

I am using this script to transpose the table :

transpose.py

```
import csv

data = zip(*csv.reader(open("input.csv", "rb")))
csv.writer(open("output.csv", "wb")).writerows(data)
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not pure python but if you're able to use the pandas library it's easy:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('input.csv', header=None)
df.transpose().to_excel('output.csv', header=None, index=None)
```

Comment: BTW I ran your code above and it seemed to work fine. Are you sure it's not an issue with whatever program you're using the view the output?

Comment: I think there is no issue with the program I use to view it.  I use EMEditor to view it. Somehow it produced the result like that. I ran your answer but it produced an error : 

pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 2, saw 3